# Is it plagiarism to hire a freelance programmer for an assignment but change a lot of it before you submit it?

Tags: masters, ethics, plagiarism, cheating, code

I took freelancer tutor help for a Python programming coursework  during my MS but did not submit the exact code he gave, I refracted it and changed a lot of it. Is it considered plagiarism?

I am asking this question to clear the self-guilt and to know more about code plagiarism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Took external help](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72101/took-external-help)

Comment: Please don't evade the rules by breaking more rules. All you're going to get is a crowd of people who are irritated with you and have no reason to help you.

Comment: @chipbuster I don't think it's a duplicate, because that question asks whether the professor will give a good recommendation. This question asks something different.

Comment: @ff524 fair enough. Would the usual protocol be to edit the first question for reopening? (I lurk the SE a fair bit, but I'm still not that familiar with all the rules)

Comment: @chipbuster Not really, the [first question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72101/took-external-help) is asking something else that is fundamentally unanswerable; there's no point in editing it to turn it into something else completely. We will just let that one stay closed and eventually get deleted.

Comment: what is your purpose for asking the question: because of your own guilt, or because you were 'caught' plagiarizing?

Comment: First I think if you're doing something in the MS level and freelancing and reediting some code there's a very big problem. Note hard work pays. Always try to be unique work hard for it. I would not suggest hiring someone to do my work, then leave alone plagiarism I'd have a guilt of being lazy and not being honest. No matter what you changed it still remains the ideas were his. Try being unique you never know. Success though :)

Comment: @J.Roibal - own guilt .

Comment: Rohan: Yes, you committed academic dishonesty and plagiarism. Since you were not caught, you will not be facing any disciplinary actions that would accompany being caught or found out in this situation. What you have done is similar to 'cheating' in a relationship. Although there are no external consequences, your conscience has (accurately) taken stock of the situation and you feel bad because you acted incorrectly. The best you can do is accept you acted inappropriately and resolve to NEVER make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 14):

If you used code that you paid someone else to write (or found for free online) for an assignment and don't disclose it, then you have plagiarized.

Plagiarism is the practice of using someone else's work and pretending it is your own, in a situation where there is an expectation of originality (as there is in coursework assignments).

If you use someone else's work and you disclose it (by citing it and telling the professor you have done so), and then build on that work by adding your own work, then you haven't plagiarized. You may not have done a good job on the assignment - your professor may decide that the work you have done on your own is not sufficient to earn a good grade, or your professor may set a rule that students are not allowed to use outside sources and then penalize you for not following the parameters of the assignment; but as long as you are honest about the source of the work, it isn't plagiarism.

But it is absolutely required that you make it clear what part of the work is not your own, and what parts are your original contributions.

Comment: This particular coursework was a high-end python glue-ware application involving many open-source libraries . I used his inputs and logic but changed the code(i understood how libraries worked and the logic) and went onto to refactor the code for 2 of my classmates.I made a mistake by not mentioning his name for initial solution . I do feel bad about it.

Comment: @RohanGupta Regardless of whether you mentioned his name, did you make it clear in your project submission how much was bought and how much was your own work?

Comment: NO . Honestly i did not knew about mentioning the this , back in the day . My only intention was to understand , learn and then do it myself.